# Play framework 2.1.3 with guice

Tags: playframework, guice, playframework-2.1

I know play provide the Global#getControllerInstance to support guice DI to Controller class.

But this way seems only work for Controller class, now I want to inject some of my service class into other class(not the class extend Controller). how can I do it?

I google a lot and cannot found the solution yet...

Comment: Just use a regular Guice injection; take a look at this article for an example: http://eng.42go.com/play-framework-dependency-injection-guice/

Comment: hi, nico, this link is describe the way use Global#getControllerInstance, and config the routes with @, but this only  work for controller class.

Comment: hi, nico, tks, I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your modules set up ([the blog post linked above is helpful](http://eng.42go.com/play-framework-dependency-injection-guice/)), you can just use direct injection or constructor injection as you normally would, unrelated to Play!. Constructor injection example:

```
class SomeClass @Inject() (dependencyA: DependencyA, userRepo: UserRepo) {
  // then, use `dependencyA` and `userRepo`
}
```

Then, from inside a controller, just inject an instance of `SomeClass`.

See [scala-guice](https://github.com/codingwell/scala-guice/) for a better API in Scala for guice.